# What's the difference between running the application from netbeans and running the jar?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have a java application that works perfectly when running from Netbeans 7.1 but it crashes if I use the build jar.

I've been investigating the problem and I've noticed that the application holds on calling DriverManager.getConnection().

I'm doing something like:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:2304;user=username;password=12345;database=databasename");
```

I've also tried jtds but it has the same result.

I'm running on Windows 7 Home Premium
SQL Server 2008 (localhost) 
Netbeans 7.1 (application works fine when running from Netbeans)
Java Version 1.6

Thread dump

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
    at joomlasyncrnzr.JoomlaSyncrnzrApp.getCon(JoomlaSyncrnzrApp.java:314)
    at joomlasyncrnzr.JoomlaSyncrnzrApp.taxas(JoomlaSyncrnzrApp.java:604)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(Ap
licationAction.java:662)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicatinAction.java:698)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Define "crashes". A Stacktrace would help.

Comment: I don't have a stacktrace since the application just holds after calling getConnection. No exception thrown and the GUI stops responding.

Comment: @woozy can you take a thread dump to see what is going on ?

Comment: @r0ast3d no. I've tried control+break but i was not hable to get the thread dump...

Comment: can you edit your original post to add more details abt the environment and other details to debug this issue.

Comment: @r0ast3d just added database anda operating system details.

Comment: Check the possible properties you can set for the Microsoft and JTDS drivers to see if you can set some sort of timeout for establishing connections. The default might be rather long or even indefinite. Set it to a couple seconds and see what happens.

Comment: @G_H good tip. I added lockTimeout to my connection string and now the application does not hang. But obviously is failing to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: I think you'll need loginTimeout rather than lockTimeout, although it must be doing something if this gives a different result already. Maybe the database reached its maximum connection limit? Or your firewall settings are blocking (even though it's localhost)? Perhaps you can go in with WireShark to see what actually moves over the network. Unfortunately I don't see some useful debugging properties in the MS driver or jTDS.

Comment: Tried loginTimeout but it has no effect.The strange thing is that if i run the application from netbeans it just works.

Comment: @woozy can you please manually try Thread.dumpStack before calling the connection

Comment: @r0ast3d added dump stack to question

Comment: This is helpful, but I think we'll have to go for a thread dump while the program hangs to see what method in what thread is stuck. It's also odd that loginTimeout doesn't do anything but lockTimeout will result in the exception. Are you sure the problem is in obtaining the connection and not executing a query that causes a deadlock? Is anything still holding a lock on a table/row? Tried restarting the SQL server yet?

Comment: @G_H yes I have restarted sql server. Also if I pass wrong user/password the application throws the correct exception when I call getConnection. What I could verify is that the application hangs forever waiting for the getConnection() with correct credentials. So, the authentication works, but there is no reply from the database. If I had the lockTimeout the getConnection will return null as expected and the application will give error message.

Comment: Running out of ideas... Since this occurs with both drivers it's obviously not a driver issue. The remaining things I can think of is to create a very small class with a main method that does nothing more than loading the driver and trying to establish a connection, to see if something else in your stack is responsible for it. If that fails as well, it's gotta be network-related or some server-side issue. Check profiling, logging and debugging options for SQL Server.

Comment: Me too... Just don't know what else to do. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the DriverManager.getConnection call just hanging indefinitely.

What solved the problem for me was going back to Java 6 Update 25. Update 29 seems to introduce a bug with the JDBC connection to SQL Server. I think Update 27 (or earlier) still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not setting your CLASSPATH to include the SQL Server driver when running the jar file, whereas Netbeans probably has it included for you already.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have the correct classpath. Also, if that was the problem, an exception whould be throwed and it's not the case. The application just holds.